# CollectionView in Xamarin.Forms using custom renderers

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have Xaml form from which I an rendering the collection view

XAML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomRenderer_POC;assembly=CustomRenderer_POC" 
             x:Class="CustomRenderer_POC.GalleryPage">
  <Label Text="{Binding MainText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  <local:CollectionView/>
</ContentPage>
```

CollectionView.CS

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
namespace CustomRenderer_POC
{
    public class CollectionView : ContentView
    {

    }
}
```

CollectionViewRender.cs (in iOS project)

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;
using CustomRenderer_POC;
using CoreGraphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CollectionView), typeof(CollectionViewRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer_POC
{
    class CollectionViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CollectionView, UICollectionView>
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CollectionView> e)
        {
            var layout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            SetNativeControl(new UICollectionView(new CGRect(0, 0, 300, 256), new UICollectionViewLayout()));
            if (Control != null)
            {
                int[] a = new int[] {10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
                Control.Source = new CollectionViewSource(a);
                Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
                Control.ReloadData();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

CollectionViewSource.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using CoreGraphics;
using CustomRenderer_POC;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(UICollectionViewSource), typeof(CollectionViewSource))]
namespace CustomRenderer_POC
{
    class CollectionViewSource : UICollectionViewSource
    {
        public Array items = null;
        public CollectionViewSource(Array elements)
        {
            items = elements;
        }
        public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

        }

        public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UICollectionViewCell cell = (UICollectionViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("MyCell", indexPath);
            cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            UILabel li = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 0, 10, 20));
            li.Text = "xyz";
            cell.AddSubview(li);
            return cell;
        }
        public override nint NumberOfSections(UICollectionView collectionView)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
        {
            return items.Length;
        }
    }

}
```

Now the point is,

I have added a break point at all methods.

But, the methods **GetCell** and **ItemSelected** are never gets hit.

Can anyone help...

I followed so many blogs but nothing helps

I bit new to "**xamarin**" platform

Final output I get is : [Output of above program in iOS simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiRGF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't produce blue screen as you said.
First issue in inheritance from `ContentView`:

```
public class CollectionView : ContentView
```

Do not use `ContentView` for "empty" views where is main logic in renderers. It's required that `Content` property set. Or rendering of this control will be skipped. Try to inherit your `CollectionView` from `View` class.

Second, I changed your renderer:

```
    if (Control == null) {
        SetNativeControl (new UICollectionView (new CGRect (0, 0, 300, 256), new UICollectionViewFlowLayout ()));
        Control.RegisterClassForCell(typeof(UICollectionViewCell), "MyCell");
    }
```

I changed your `UICollectionViewLayout` to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`.
According to Apple documentation, it's a abstract base class:

> The UICollectionViewLayout class is an abstract base class that you
>   subclass and use to generate layout information for a collection view.

But Apple provides us ready to use implementation - `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Hope this helps